# Scroll bar hide after SetScrollInfo() call

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a problem with scrollbar. I'm trying to save scrollbar position before refresh scrollbar and then set saved position again. I use the following code:

```
SCROLLINFO si;
GetScrollInfo(SB_VERT, &si);
//Then I do stuff related with refresh
SetItemCountEx((int)moElements.GetSize(), LVSICF_NOINVALIDATEALL);
// Then stuff that sort elements...
Invalidate();
SetScrollInfo(SB_VERT,&si);
```

After this, `CListCtrl` shown without scrollbar (scrollbar just hide somewhere) and it shows after I select and with down button move thru the list.
What may cause this behavior? PS: Nothing change if I call `SetScrollInfo(SB_VERT,&si)` before `Invalidate()`.

Way with `EnsureVisible` works partially. I can use `EnsureVisible`, but `GetTopIndex` always returns `0`.

Comment: See answer to this question [CListCtrl: How to maintain scroll position?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7612067/4603670) You may also want to begin and end with `SetRedraw(FALSE)` and `SetRedraw(TRUE)` to reduce flicker.

Comment: Why do you at the beginning of this code get horizontal scroll info, and at the end trying to set vertical scroll info?

Comment: For some reason, GetTopIndex () always returns 0. Also after I scroll the list.

Comment: `GetTopIndex` doesn't always work, see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb761087(v=vs.85).aspx). Are any of those conditions true?

Answer (score -1):

Hope your SetScrollInfo and GetScrollInfo are not windows api since windows api takes HWND as your first argument.

Hi, I guess you should be doing this.

```
SCROLLINFO si = {};
si.cbSize = sizeof(SCROLLINFO);//This step is always required for backward compatibility
si.fMask = SIF_POS;
GetScrollInfo(Window,SB_VERT,&si);
//Do your stuff.
UINT scrollBarPos = si.nPos;//Save currentPos
SetScrollInfo(Window,SB_VERT,&si,true);
//true parameter will tell Windows to invalidate the screen and redraw.
//No need to call InvalidateRect.
```

Comment: kindly consider adding this as a comment instead

Comment: I'd say that the OP code was written in MFC, hence the missing HWND parameter.  This answer isn't an answer.  As @Inder said, it should have been a comment.

Comment: @Jesus Christ I am having flickering scrollbar when I try to resize my scrollbar when page size is greater than max size. Any ideas why?