Preserve ScrollBar & Window position after resizing the Dialog
I have a MFC based Dialog application. I would like to preserve the previous scrolled position of the window and reshow the same position after resizing the dialog. How can I achieve it?
I am using OnSize() Method to handle the Window Resizing.  Could you please provide a logic to preserve and reshow the previous window & scrollbar position after resizing

Something like this? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7612067/4641116

Please add some code. More specifically, your OnSize() current implementation (as is), and preferably your OnVScroll() as well (or the way you are handling scrolling).

Quite complicated. I would override the OnSize() member, where I would first get the current scroll positions, call the base class member, and then do some calculations so that the middle of the window before resizing remains in the middle after resizing, and finally scroll to the new position. It may not be very accurate as you have limitations, for example the scroll range gets smaller as the window grows larger. Check the Get/SetScrollPosition(),  Get/SetScrollRange() and Get/SetScrollInfo() functions. They are Win32 functions, also available as CWnd class members (MFC is to a large extend a Win32 wrapper after all).
However I think that this is a rather poor UI design. Dialog-boxes that display scroll-bars are not ergonomic, as the user has to scroll to display the desired controls. Dialog-boxes should instead display all controls, ie the dialog resource should fit exactly in the window's client area, and NOT having a resizable border. The dialog should be small enough to fit in the screen for the resolution(s) of the target machines; if you can't fit all controls you should consider other solutions like resizing/repositioning the controls or using tabbed pages. Also, a dialog-box is basically meant to be used as a pop-up window, not as an application's main window ("overlapped"). Many MFC developers choose the "Dialog Application" option, because it's easily available, and for it's supposed simplicity. The best option imo is an SDI application without document/view support (uncheck the option). It still contains a view object though. The view-type can be CFormView, which is a dialog-resource-based view, and the application behaves better, supports features like the ON_UPDATE_COMMAND_UI handlers, and offers goodies like toolbars, status-bar and dockable panes, all generated by the Wizard. That is, it's a proper application, not a dialog-box repurposed as an application window.
